# Calculate mean across several rows based on ID and condition and reshape into wide-format

Tags: r, dataframe, long-format-data

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate a mean across several row values (long format table) for participants and subsequently reshape the data in a wide format. Here is my use case example including missing data (just as my real df):

```
condition<-c("Participant 1 - Analysis 1","Participant 1 - Analysis 2","Participant 1 - Analysis 3","Participant 1 - Analysis 4","Participant 1 - Analysis 5","Participant 1 - Analysis 6",
             "Participant 2 - Analysis 1","Participant 2 - Analysis 2","Participant 2 - Analysis 3","Participant 2 - Analysis 4","Participant 2 - Analysis 5","Participant 2 - Analysis 6",
             "Participant 3 - Analysis 1","Participant 3 - Analysis 2","Participant 3 - Analysis 3","Participant 3 - Analysis 4","Participant 3 - Analysis 5","Participant 3 - Analysis 6")
value<-c(5,3,5,7,2,3,8,NA,8,2,4,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
id<-c("d1","d1","d1","d1","d1","d1","d2","d2","d2","d2","d2","d2","d3","d3","d3","d3","d3","d3")
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(condition,value,id))
```

The solution I am looking for is something like this, including the mean for any cases **per condition** with at least 2 valid values but also missings (participant 2):

[image]

I really appreciate any hints on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)
library(tidyr)
 df %>%
   select(-condition) %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(grp2 =as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n()))) %>%
   group_by(grp2, .add = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(value = if(sum(!is.na(value)) >=2) value else NA) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = grp2, values_from = value, values_fn = fmean)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  id      `1`   `2`   `3`
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 d1        4     6   2.5
2 d2       NA     5   3.5
3 d3       NA    NA  NA
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that I need to capture the information of which condition this is from...also, the reframe-function can't be found by my version of R despite having loaded the indicated packages

Comment: Somehow, this is not working. I do get an error "Error in select(., -Condition) : unused argument (-condition)".

Comment: @Jan Probably you loaded a package with same function select that masked the `dplyr::select`.  Can you add the namespace i.e. `dplyr::select(-condition)`

Comment: thanks for your help, that seemed to have solved one issue but I do get another error: "Error: ´n ()´ must only be used inside dplyr verbs." Any ideas on how do solve that? the backtrace says: Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
  8. plyr::mutate(., grp2 = as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n())))
  9. [ base::eval(...) ] with 1 more call
 12. dplyr::n()
 13. dplyr:::peek_mask("n()")
 14. dplyr:::context_peek("mask", fun)
 15. context_peek_bare(name) %||% abort(glue("`{fun}` must only be used inside {location}."))